# How to reference "this" argument in a called function

Tags: javascript, this

I've coded a simple game where a gun, when clicked, shoots a bullet to hit a moving target (or 'ship' as they are referred to in class names) of which there are 3 classes of targets with varying speeds, time intervals and locations. I have my collision function set up to detect when a bullet makes contact with any of the targets. However I can't figure out how to to apply a collision consequence (turn 'this' ship red, score 50 points, etc.) to the specific target that the bullet collided with.

http://jsbin.com/cujuxuha/7/

**JS**

```
setInterval(function() {
    if (collisions($('.allShips'), $('.bullet'))) {
        $(???).css('background-color','red');
        score = + 50;
        $('#score').text(score);
    }
}, 25);
```

Comment: Read through the related questions. (`this` is set dynamically based on how the currently executing function was invoked; use closures and/or Function.bind to guarantee access to a particular object.)

Comment: Your `collisions` function will have to tell this code (by `return`ing) what the bullet hit. Then you do what you want in the code provided above

Comment: that or make your `collisions` function take a call back for items that are actually colliding. then something like `$(this)` would probably make sense.

Comment: You assume $('.allShips') has one element, but it might not... do an each over it... $('.allShips').each(function(idx, ship){ logic }); and pass in all of the stuff inside the setInterval. collisions($('.allShips') becomes collisions(ship, and ??? becomes ship.

Comment: Thanks everyone - I'm also having trouble coding which specific elements are actually involved in a collision and then how it's applied to the if statement inside the setInterval function.